# Drawing a polygon over a point in OpenLayers

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geojson, point

I read a geojson with points and their coordinates, but on the map, I want to draw polygons, not points.

this is an example of the polygon that I want:

[image]
Yes, it is a boat.

How can I do it?

Comment: what language are you using? if java you can simply take the points and recreate the output as a GeoJson Polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way will be to go through all the points and create the polygon geometry by yourself. Polygon is in openLayers represented as [aray of arrays of coordinates](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html) for example `[[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,0]]]` where the last coordinate is allways the same as the first. So you can do something like this:

```
var pointsFeatures = geojson.features;//correct definition of your data
var pointsArray = [];
for(var i = 0;i<pointsFeatures.length;i++){
  pointsArray.push(pointsFeatures[i].geometry.coordinates);
}
pointsArray.push(pointsFeatures[0].geometry.coordinates);
var feat = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(pointsArray)
})
yourVectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(feat);
```

This will work in case you have no holes in that polygon.